# How can I load .jpg images in directory under directory?

Tags: python, loadimage

I need to load images such as 001.jpg, 045.jpg, etc.. in directory "0000045", but there are other image directory in folder "image". My code was this;

```
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\dg\image'
file_list = glob.glob(path)
file_list_jpg = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith(".jpg")]

print ("file_list_py: {}".format(file_list_jpg))
```

but the result was

> file_list_py: []

I want to see 001.jpg or else but there was nothing :(
Can anybody help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Directory root Structure is ,

```
Image--
      |
      0000045--
              |
              (Image files with ".jpg" or anyother format )
```

But according to your code ,

```
path = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\dg\image'
file_list = glob.glob(path)
```

You are accessing image directory which contains all other directory ( like 0000045 dir ).
So the file_list will be of the directory names.

```
file_list_jpg = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith(".jpg")]
```

Hence there are no names in file_list which ends with .jpg .So the list is empty .

Inorder to access the image files ,

```
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\dg\image'

dir_list = glob.glob(path)
file_list = []
for directory in dir_list:
    path = r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\dg\image' +"\"+directory
    file_list += glob.glob(path)

file_list_jpg = [file for file in file_list if file.endswith(".jpg")]
```